# Sorting Tags by Slug Value

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tags

In wordpress the tags are display alphabetically by default. How can I sort the tags by slug value and keep that order in the front end?

Answer (score 1):

You can set orderby slug like :

```
$tags = get_tags( 'order=ASC&orderby=slug' );

$html = '<div class="post_tags">';
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );

    $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
    $html .= "{$tag->name}</a>";
}
$html .= '</div>';
echo $html;
```